# R markdown, hiding the library output

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am working on a `rmarkdown` presentation. I am trying to show the usage of `cast` function. However, since the `reshape` package is necessary, to run the `cast` function, I need to load reshape library as below.

```
{r package_options, echo=TRUE}
library(reshape)
cast(datam, isim~Ay, value="Sirano")
```

However, after knitting the codes, I face with the output ;
[image]

I just need to see the name of the library on the screen which is `library(reshape)` , and also I want it to be used to run `cast` function, but I dont want to see the package outputs as shown in the picture.

Would someone help about that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `messages=FALSE`.

Comment: or `invisible(library(reshape))`

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło That wouldn't suppress the messages

Comment: @Dason I tried it several times and it does supress them. At least when I knit my .Rmd file to HTML.

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło It doesn't suppress the warning about the package being built on a later version of R for me. And if plyr is loaded it doesn't suppress the warnings about masked objects.  You would need to use `suppressWarnings` and `suppressPackageStartupMessages` in conjuction if you wanted to handle loading reshape directly instead of using a chunk option.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to hide all these messages you have to put :

````
```{r,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
library(reshape)
```
````